# What is the tdp_page_fault used for?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am working on a QEMU-KVM hypervisor, and i'd like to understand the purpose of tdp_page_fault.
In fact, i need to count the page faults due to the virtual machine execution and it seems that tdp_page_fault handles more page faults than what i talked about. so what is tdp_page_fault used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On simple processors, a lot of the kernel stuff needs to be emulated because it is actually running in user space.  On high-end x86 we can do TDP ([two-dimensional paging](https://lwn.net/Articles/832835/)) where the page table lookup for both the guest->host and the host->physical are done in hardware, so much faster than emulation.

`tdp_page_fault` handles a page fault in the guest address space.